# how to deploy visual studio "sql server database project" on another (client) system?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, database-project

i have create database project for database deployment on client side sql server.. but there is only Deploy option in visual studio which deploy database on running system.. how can i deploy this project on client machine ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Publish option. It's very similar to Deploy but you can create a publishing profile for each machine.

You could use the Deploy option but each time you'd have to change the connection string in the Debug tab in the project's properties.

Comment: i cant find publish option for database project in visual studio 2010, tried > Right click on solution > but in menu there is  no publish option. Deploy is there